# How to store element of multiple input image in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

Hello I'm new to this and sorry for my bad English

I want to store image element in variable and send to server.

I use this code:

```
 $("#input-fa").fileinput({
        showUpload: false,
        language: 'th',
        uploadUrl: "#",
        allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg'],
        overwriteInitial: false,
        maxFileSize: 1000,
        maxFileCount: 3,
        autoReplace: false
    });
```

in save button function I try this:

```
var myFile = $('#input-fa').prop('files');
```

and

```
var myFile = document.getElementById("input-fa");
```

the problem is: If I select one or two images once then browse one or two more , I will get only the last set object that I browse.

Is there any way to make it can browse multiple times ?

Comment: I've not used this specific plugin, but maybe change: `maxFileCount: 3` to something higher?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using AJAX for this :

```
<input id="input-fa" name="imageupload[]" type="file" multiple=true/>
<script>
$("#input-702").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "http://localhost/file-loc/", // server upload action
    uploadAsync: true,
    minFileCount: 1,
    maxFileCount: 5,
    overwriteInitial: false,
});
</script>
```